# Quick question about binary strings

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, binary

Determine the unambigious expression which generates every string in this set.
The set of all binary strings which contains 001111 as a substring.

I am thinking that the answer should be

{0,1}$^*${001111}{0,1}$^*$

But the answer says that it should be

{0,1}$^*$\{1}$^*$({00}{0}$^*${1,11,111}∪{0}{1}{1}$^*$)$^*${0}$^*$

Which is basically to take all the strings, and remove those that do not contain 001111 as a substring. Is my answer correct also, or is the 2nd one more correct?

Sorry if this is in the wrong section, as I couldn't find the Binary strings tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is not correct, for the following reason: if a binary string contains more than one copy of `001111`, then it can be represented as you suggest *in more than one way*.  (For instance, the first instance of `001111` could be absorbed in to the first glob and the second could be the required one; or, the first instance could be the required one, and the second absorbed in to the tail.)

Comment: Ah that's what I forgot. I forgot that this needs to be an unambiguous expression. I get it now :) Now I just need to know how to formulate this decomposition. Thanks!

Comment: Why would the expression $\{0.999\cdots,1\} = \{1\}$ be wrong? I guess what I mean is that the same thing can have two or more different representations. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @LordSoth Unless I completely miss my guess, he's essentially been asked to come up with a way of counting binary strings of this type. As such, each such string needs a unique representation.

Comment: @LordSoth (I base this assumption on the generating-function tag, on the use of the term 'unambiguous', and on his seeming agreement with my answer.  But I could be wrong!)

Comment: @nrpeterson OK, thank you, I was just wondering if there is an important convention that I was not aware regarding these binary strings. I shall perhaps check it out later.